# date formatting is painful across the browsers

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime, datepicker

In my project I am using angularJS and momentJS for fixing the painful date formating part. I have two scenarios, here we go:

1. Retrieving the date from db and rendering it in UI:
   I am getting the response from service in this formate "2016-01-31T20:30:00.000Z". I am using the above and rendering the date and time separately in the following way in UI

   ```
    <input ng-model="data.startDate" type="date" name="startDate" disabled>
    <input ng-model="data.startDate" type="time" name="startTime" disabled>
   ```

Its displaying like the image attached below[image]

Its being displayed as YYYY-MM-DD in firefox and in the chrome as DD-MM-YYYY. I want to use the same object for displaying the date and time maintaining the date formate across all the browsers. How it can be achieved ?

2. I am using [this](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker) datepicker. When the user selects the date I want show the date in the same format. In this scenario date and time inputs are taken separately and combined in the background.

So can someone help me in fixing the issue.

Comment: Why not simply convert the date time from DB and return it as a parsed string which conforms to the format you want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert all date format into string like .ToString("YYYY-MM-DD")
2. Format datepicker as  dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: Hello, Tony! I just came across [an edit you suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19994628). When you edit, please put the edit summary in the edit summary field. Please do not put the summary in the post itself. When you put it in the post, somebody has to come in after you and remove it. (For example, see Revision 3 on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50257465/revisions).) Thanks for all the edits you do!